# Python not recognizing websockets.broadcast()

Tags: python, websocket, server, tcp

I'm trying to run the following code for a simple chat server:

```
import asyncio
import websockets


async def chat(websocket, debug):
    print(debug, type(debug))
    while True:
        message = await websocket.recv()
        await websockets.broadcast(message)
    
async def main():
    async with websockets.serve(chat, "localhost", 8008):
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        await asyncio.Future()

if (__name__ == "__main__"):
    print(websockets.__file__)
    asyncio.run(main())
```

However when I do this I get the following error:
`AttributeError: module 'websockets' has no attribute 'broadcast'`

I tried going through the code of the module imported and made sure I had no files named websockets.py. Not sure why this is as this should be the latest version of websockets as well.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the full import for broadcast?

```
from websockets.legacy.protocol import broadcast
```